# creating a docker image with the same name

Tags: docker

I am using Dockerfiles to try to create my builds automatically.  I'm trying to understand the layer concept.  In my Dockerfile I already add the version of Mono I need and I am writing a C# application that mono calls.  As I'm developing the app, I'm just adding the src files I need to the Docker image, then run the container.  So every time I create a new build for my C# application, I basically just copy over the new C# files.  If in my Dockerfile, it is something simple like this:

```
FROM centos
// install mono
ADD . /src
```

when I run the build I do

```
docker build -t="crystal/testapp" .
```

when I update my host machine's C# source files, and I run the docker build command again.  Is this adding another layer to my last crystal/testapp image.  Or is it starting at centos base and just creating a brand new image that replaces my old crystal/testapp image?  Looking at the size of my image, it seems like it is not replacing the old one but doing somethign else that I'm not sure of. The size is only relatively consistent if I `docker rmi hash` before each build which seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the contents of . change, docker will start from the centos base.  There is a new layer, but is a child of centos, rather than of your previous layer.